# Typescript: `this` types and generic functions

Tags: typescript, polymorphism

Let's say I want to create an interface `addable`, which describes classes with a method `__add__` which adds the objects of a class to an other object of the same class.

Let's also say I want to have a stand-alone function `add` which takes two `addable` objects of the same class and returns their sum.

My first take was to use the `this` type in the interface:

```
interface addable<T> {
    __add__: (this: T, other: T) => T;
}
```

Then I implement my class as follows:

```
class Point implements addable {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
    __add__(other: Point) {
        return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }
}
```

Which fails with:

> Class 'Point' incorrectly implements interface 'addable'.
>
> Types of property '**add**' are incompatible. Type '(other: Point) => Point' is not assignable to type '(other: this) => this'.
>
> Type 'Point' is not assignable to type 'this'.

EDIT: after some research I've found out that the `this` type refers to the `this` object, not to the class of the `this` object. So this attempt was doomed to fail.

See [the example 1](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20addable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20__add__%3A%20(other%3A%20this)%20%3D%3E%20this%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Point%20implements%20addable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20__add__(other%3A%20Point)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Point(this.x%20%2B%20other.x%2C%20this.y%20%2B%20other.y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20add%20%3D%20(a1%3A%20addable%2C%20a2%3A%20addable)%20%3D%3E%20a1.__add__(a2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20p1%20%3D%20new%20Point(10%2C%2020)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20p2%20%3D%20new%20Point(20%2C%2030)%3B%0D%0Ap1.__add__(p2)%0D%0Aadd(p1%2C%20p2)).

My second take was to use generics with `this` pseudo-parameter:

```
interface addable<T> {
    __add__: (this: T, other: T) => T;
}
```

The class definition as specified above works in this case. However, when I try to define the standalone `add`:

```
const add = <T>(a1: addable<T>, a2: addable<T>) => a1.__add__(a2);
```

I get:

> The 'this' context of type 'addable' is not assignable to method's
>   'this' of type 'T'.

See [the example 2](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20addable%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20__add__%3A%20(this%3A%20T%2C%20other%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Point%20implements%20addable%3CPoint%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20x%3A%20number%2C%20public%20y%3A%20number)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20__add__(other%3A%20Point)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Point(this.x%20%2B%20other.x%2C%20this.y%20%2B%20other.y)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20add%20%3D%20%3CT%3E(a1%3A%20addable%3CT%3E%2C%20a2%3A%20addable%3CT%3E)%20%3D%3E%20a1.__add__(a2)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20p1%20%3D%20new%20Point(10%2C%2020)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20p2%20%3D%20new%20Point(20%2C%2030)%3B%0D%0Ap1.__add__(p2))

Does anyone have any idea how to implement the desired behaviour?

EDIT2:

The interface

```
interface Addable<T> {
    add: (this: Addable<T>, other: Addable<T>) => Addable<T>;
}
```

is apparently what I want. The stand-alone function would then be

```
const add = <T>(a1: Addable<T>, a2: Addable<T>) => a1.add(a2)
```

But this definition is too permissive. It actually typechecks with any two instances of `Addable`, not just with with ones of the same class

```
interface Addable<T> {
    add: (this: Addable<T>, other: Addable<T>) => Addable<T>;
}
class Point implements Addable<Point> {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
    add(other: Point) {
        return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }
}
class Num implements Addable<Num> {
    constructor(public number: number) { }
    add(other: Num) {
        return new Num(this.number + other.number);
    }
}
const add = <T>(a1: Addable<T>, a2: Addable<T>) => a1.add(a2)

var p1 = new Point(1, 1);
var num1 = new Num(10);

const wrongAdded = p1.add(num1);  // correctly fails

const wrongAdded2 = add(p1, num1);  // typechecks! why???
```

The inferred type of add is `<{}>`. Which doesn't sound right, but I'm not familiar with typescript enough to claim any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last version from the question was almost there. I used wrong syntax to the constraint on the generic type. The final version looks like this

```
interface Addable<T> {
    add: (this: Addable<T>, other: Addable<T>) => Addable<T>;
}
class Point implements Addable<Point> {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }
    add(other: Point) {
        return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }
}

class Num implements Addable<Num> {
    constructor(public number: number) { }
    add(other: Num) {
        return new Num(this.number + other.number);
    }
}
const add: <T extends Addable<T>>(a1: T, a2: T) => T = function (a1, a2) {
    return a1.add(a2);
}

var p1 = new Point(1, 1);
var p2 = new Point(2, 2);
var num1 = new Num(10);

const added = p1.add(p2);
const added2 = add(p1, p2);

const wrongAdded = p1.add(num1);  // Fails

const wrongAdded2 = add(p1, num1);  // Fails
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this achieve what you want... I have removed the parameter `this` entirely. If it was needed, I would have renamed it. This allows one point to be added to another, returning the resulting point...

```
interface Addable<T> {
    add: (other: T) => T;
}

class Point implements Addable<Point> {
    constructor(public x: number, public y: number) { }

    add(other: Point) {
        return new Point(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }
}

var p1 = new Point(1, 1);
var p2 = new Point(3, 3);

var added = p1.add(p2);

alert(added.x + ' ' + added.y);
```

Note: I have adjusted names in here to make them a bit more aligned with TypeScript in the wild - as I don't want other programmers to copy/paste your conventions into production. You are free to use the names `addable` and `__add__` if you want to though :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would you implement the stand-alone method add(a1, a2) then?

Comment: I've figured it out! The interface has to be ```interface Addable<T> {
    add: (this: Addable<T>, other: Addable<T>) => Addable<T>;
}``` and the function `const add = <T>(a1: Addable<T>, a2: Addable<T>) => a1.add(a2)`. The reason why I want to have the this-parameter, is so you can only add two object of the same class, not just any two `Addable` objects.

Comment: Premature joy :) That solution allows you to `add` any two `Addable`s, not just of the same class.